# How to implement an intrusive list in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am following along with the book Crafting Interpreters. On [chapter 25](http://craftinginterpreters.com/closures.html#closed-upvalues), when implementing closures, the author used an intrusive list to keep track of open upvalues. I am trying to rewrite the example code in Rust, with reference to the [Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/fifth.html) guide. Here is the code from the book:

```c
static ObjUpvalue* captureUpvalue(Value* local) {
//> look-for-existing-upvalue
  ObjUpvalue* prevUpvalue = NULL;
  ObjUpvalue* upvalue = vm.openUpvalues;
  while (upvalue != NULL && upvalue->location > local) {
    prevUpvalue = upvalue;
    upvalue = upvalue->next;
  }

  if (upvalue != NULL && upvalue->location == local) {
    return upvalue;
  }

//< look-for-existing-upvalue
  ObjUpvalue* createdUpvalue = newUpvalue(local);
//> insert-upvalue-in-list
  createdUpvalue->next = upvalue;

  if (prevUpvalue == NULL) {
    vm.openUpvalues = createdUpvalue;
  } else {
    prevUpvalue->next = createdUpvalue;
  }

//< insert-upvalue-in-list
  return createdUpvalue;
}
//< Closures capture-upvalue
//> Closures close-upvalues
static void closeUpvalues(Value* last) {
  while (vm.openUpvalues != NULL &&
         vm.openUpvalues->location >= last) {
    ObjUpvalue* upvalue = vm.openUpvalues;
    upvalue->closed = *upvalue->location;
    upvalue->location = &upvalue->closed;
    vm.openUpvalues = upvalue->next;
  }
}
```

The following is the code I managed to come up with:

```rust
fn capture_upvalue(&mut self, location: usize, value: Value) -> *mut ObjUpvalue {
    let mut prev_upvalue: *mut ObjUpvalue = std::ptr::null_mut();
    let cur_upvalue = self.open_upvalues;
    unsafe {
        loop {
            if cur_upvalue.is_null() || (*cur_upvalue).location <= location {
                break;
            }
            prev_upvalue = cur_upvalue;
            cur_upvalue.swap((*cur_upvalue).next);
         }
         if !cur_upvalue.is_null() && (*cur_upvalue).location == location {
            return cur_upvalue;
         }

         let created_upvalue = Box::into_raw(allocate_upvalue(location, value));
         (*created_upvalue).next = cur_upvalue;
            
         if prev_upvalue.is_null() {
            self.open_upvalues = created_upvalue;
            assert!((*self.open_upvalues).next.is_null());
         } else {
            (*prev_upvalue).next.swap(created_upvalue);
         }

         return created_upvalue;
    }
}

fn close_upvalues(&mut self, start: u8) {
    unsafe {
        loop {
            if self.open_upvalues.is_null() || (*self.open_upvalues).location < start.into() {
                break;
            }

            let upvalue = self.open_upvalues;
            (*upvalue).closed = Box::new((*(*(self.open_upvalues)).value).clone());
            (*upvalue).value.swap((*upvalue).closed.as_mut() as *mut Value);
            self.open_upvalues = (*self.open_upvalues).next;
        }
    }
}


pub fn allocate_upvalue(location: usize, mut value: Value) -> Box<ObjUpvalue> {
    Box::new(ObjUpvalue {
        value: &mut value as *mut Value,
        closed: Box::new(Value::ValNil),
        location,
        next: std::ptr::null_mut()
    })
}
```

This code does not run correctly and results in a segfault. I am wondering if there is a solution for this problem that uses an intrusive list.

Comment: I was following the [Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists guide](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/fifth.html), where they used raw pointers to implement a linked list. I thought of trying something similar for this intrusive list.

Comment: I hadn't heard of an intrusive linked list until now, but it seems like any list with generic content in rust is automatically intrusive and non-intrusive depending on what type you put in the generic.

Comment: Please post reproducible code, something we can run.

Comment: You're using `swap` when you should not. `swap()` swaps the _content_ of the pointers. You should use a simple assignment.